# filter distinct value based on two columns with inverse string values in `r`

Tags: r, duplicates, dplyr, distinct, subset

I am trying to filter my dataset to get rid of doubled rows. However, I want to do my filter on two different column that are identical if taken inversely (Origin-Destination data). Here is an example of data:

```
data2<-matrix(NA, nrow = 7, ncol=5)  
colnames(data2)<-c("City.Pair", "Origin.City", "Destination.City", "Total.Passengers", "Total.Revenue")
data2[,1] <- c("LIS-BRU","LIS-LHR","LAD-LIS", "LIS-LAD", "FAO-MAN", "MAN-FAO","LIS-ORY")
data2[,2]<- c("LISBON", "LISBON", "LUANDA", "LISBON", "FARO", "MANCHESTER", "LISBON")
data2[,3] <- c("BRUSSELS","LONDON", "LISBON", "LUANDA", "MANCHESTER", "FARO", "PARIS" )
data2[,4] <- c(100, 5000, 200, 200, 4000, 4000, 4000)
data2[,5] <- c(100.66, 5000.25, 200.75, 200.75, 4000.10, 4000.10, 4000.05)
data2<-data.frame(data2)


  City.Pair Origin.City Destination.City Total.Passengers Total.Revenue
1   LIS-BRU      LISBON         BRUSSELS              100        100.66
2   LIS-LHR      LISBON           LONDON             5000       5000.25
3   LAD-LIS      LUANDA           LISBON              200        200.75
4   LIS-LAD      LISBON           LUANDA              200        200.75
5   FAO-MAN        FARO       MANCHESTER             4000        4000.1
6   MAN-FAO  MANCHESTER             FARO             4000        4000.1
7   LIS-ORY      LISBON            PARIS             4000       4000.05
```

I used the `dplyr` library and `distinct` which works fine with my number of passengers and revenue as with the code below:

```
library(dplyr)
data4 <- distinct(data2, Total.Passengers, Total.Revenue)
```

However, my real dataset has millions of rows and sometimes, the number of passengers, for a same city-pair, is not exactly the same (difference of decimals). But, I still need to filter the data and keep only one record so I won't be counting twice the passengers and the revenue.

Though, I am looking for a function that will allow me to filter based on the Origin and the Destination or on the City.Pair.

As part of my trials, I have tried to use the `anti_join` function by merging a doubled of the dataset but it does keep all the rows. I also tried with the `union` but got the same result.

```
data3<- data2
data5<- anti_join(data2, data3, by=c("Origin.City" = "Destination.City", "Destination.City" = "Origin.City"))
```

My desired output should be something as follow:

```
  City.Pair Origin.City Destination.City Total.Passengers Total.Revenue
1   LIS-BRU      LISBON         BRUSSELS              100        100.66
2   LIS-LHR      LISBON           LONDON             5000       5000.25
3   LAD-LIS      LUANDA           LISBON              200        200.75
4   FAO-MAN        FARO       MANCHESTER             4000        4000.1
5   LIS-ORY      LISBON            PARIS             4000       4000.05
```

What would be the best function for the task ? Or what can I correct in my actual code ?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

How can I change the code to include another condition into the filtering?
Let's say one row is coded and I also want to subset/filter based on that column.

Here is the new dataframe:

```
data2<-matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol=6)  
colnames(data2)<-c("City.Pair", "Origin.City", "Destination.City", "Total.Passengers", "Total.Revenue", "Code")
data2[,1] <- c("LIS-BRU","LIS-LHR","LAD-LIS", "LIS-LAD", "FAO-MAN", "MAN-FAO","LIS-ORY","LAD-LIS", "LAD-LIS", "LIS-LAD")
data2[,2]<- c("LISBON", "LISBON", "LUANDA", "LISBON", "FARO", "MANCHESTER", "LISBON","LUANDA", "LUANDA", "LISBON")
data2[,3] <- c("BRUSSELS","LONDON", "LISBON", "LUANDA", "MANCHESTER", "FARO", "PARIS","LISBON", "LISBON", "LUANDA")
data2[,4] <- c(100, 5000, 200, 200, 4000, 4000, 4000, 20, 40, 40)
data2[,5] <- c(100.66, 5000.25, 200.75, 200.75, 4000.10, 4000.10, 4000.05, 20.5, 40.8, 40.8)
data2[,6] <- c("F", "G","F", "F", "A", "A", "P", "H", "I", "I")
data2<-data.frame(data2)
data2

   City.Pair Origin.City Destination.City Total.Passengers Total.Revenue Code
1    LIS-BRU      LISBON         BRUSSELS              100        100.66    F
2    LIS-LHR      LISBON           LONDON             5000       5000.25    G
3    LAD-LIS      LUANDA           LISBON              200        200.75    F
4    LIS-LAD      LISBON           LUANDA              200        200.75    F
5    FAO-MAN        FARO       MANCHESTER             4000        4000.1    A
6    MAN-FAO  MANCHESTER             FARO             4000        4000.1    A
7    LIS-ORY      LISBON            PARIS             4000       4000.05    P
8    LAD-LIS      LUANDA           LISBON               20          20.5    H
9    LAD-LIS      LUANDA           LISBON               40          40.8    I
10   LIS-LAD      LISBON           LUANDA               40          40.8    I
```

So the desired output should be as follow:

```
  City.Pair Origin.City Destination.City Total.Passengers Total.Revenue Code
1   LIS-BRU      LISBON         BRUSSELS              100        100.66    F
2   LIS-LHR      LISBON           LONDON             5000       5000.25    G
3   LAD-LIS      LUANDA           LISBON              200        200.75    F
5   FAO-MAN        FARO       MANCHESTER             4000       4000.10    A
7   LIS-ORY      LISBON            PARIS             4000       4000.05    P
8   LAD-LIS      LUANDA           LISBON               20         20.50    H
9   LAD-LIS      LUANDA           LISBON               40         40.80    I
```

I am performing multiple trials but can't perform the filter on two columns at the same time.. Here is my code:

```
dat1<- 
  data2 %>%
  group_by(Code, City.Pair, Origin.City, Destination.City) %>%
  filter(Origin.City!=Destination.City & Destination.City!=Origin.City) %>%
  summarise(Passengers=sum(Total.Passengers), 
          Revenue=sum(Total.Revenue))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can split the 'City.Pair' by '-', `sort` the elements in the `list` output, `paste them together to give a`vector`, check for duplicates ('i1') and use the logical vector to subset the rows of 'data2'.

```
i1 <- !duplicated(apply(sapply(strsplit(as.character(data2$City.Pair), "-"), 
                sort), 2, paste, collapse="-"))
data2[i1,]
#    City.Pair Origin.City Destination.City Total.Passengers Total.Revenue
#1   LIS-BRU      LISBON         BRUSSELS              100        100.66
#2   LIS-LHR      LISBON           LONDON             5000       5000.25
#3   LAD-LIS      LUANDA           LISBON              200        200.75
#5   FAO-MAN        FARO       MANCHESTER             4000        4000.1
#7   LIS-ORY      LISBON            PARIS             4000       4000.05
```

---

Or using `separate` with `pmin/pmax`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
separate(data2, City.Pair, into = c("City", "City2"), remove = FALSE) %>% 
         filter(!duplicated(pmin(City, City2), pmax(City, City2))) %>%
         select(-City, -City2)
#  City.Pair Origin.City Destination.City Total.Passengers Total.Revenue
#1   LIS-BRU      LISBON         BRUSSELS              100        100.66
#2   LIS-LHR      LISBON           LONDON             5000       5000.25
#3   LAD-LIS      LUANDA           LISBON              200        200.75
#4   FAO-MAN        FARO       MANCHESTER             4000        4000.1
#5   LIS-ORY      LISBON            PARIS             4000       4000.05
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Akrun, this is very helpful. I have tested both method on my sample of data and it works perfectly. However, on my big dataset, results are different. I have used both function on my data (around 400,000 rows) and their results are at the opposite. The subset with `duplicated` kept only 42,000 rows while the one with `separate` kept 380,000 rows. I still try to figure out which has done the proper job in eliminating the duplicates.. As to your knowledge, have you faced something similar? Any clue, why is there a huge difference in the subset?

Comment: @CatherineGladu  I haven't tested on a big dataset, but my hunch is that it should work., please check for some leading/lagging spaces in the big data.  It can make some difference.  i.e. first do `data2$City.Pair <- trimws(data2$City.Pair)`

Comment: thanks for the reply. The difference did not come from the spacing. In my dataset, I have several lines with the same Airport.Pair with different number of passengers based on other criteria. Anyway, the first method only kept the first observations and deleted the others. So before applying the method, I had `group_by` and `summarise` my data to not loose any information. Then by applying the `duplicated` the  results are accurate.

Comment: however,  by applying the second method on my aggregated data, it did not work. It did not removed any duplicates..

Comment: I have edited the question and I was wondering if you have a suggestion for it : how to include another variable into the duplicates filter. I am actually using your first suggestion with `apply` but I couln'd figure out how to include another variable in it..